# Php says "question mark" equals to zero

Tags: php

Very strange question, I've never seen anything like that. Let's see the code:

```
$_POST['SCORE1'] = 4;
$_POST['SCORE2'] = 0;
var_dump ($_POST['SCORE1']);
var_dump ($_POST['SCORE2']);
var_dump ($_POST['SCORE1'] == '?');
var_dump ($_POST['SCORE2'] == '?');
```

it echoes the followings:

```
int(4) 
int(0) 
bool(false) 
bool(true)  ??? wtf ???
```

I dont understand the last one. 0 = ?

Comment: use strict comparison (`===`) when possible for avoid type juggling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this expression `$_POST['SCORE2'] == '?')` php converts the string `?` to a numerical value. When it does convert the value becomes 0. So `0==0` is true.

Comment: interesting... after many years, I didnt experience that. Php has been doing it always?

Comment: the same way POST global convers dotts `.` to `_`

Comment: yes its the loose type behavior if you compare a string with int that happens.

Comment: @DevZer0 While it is true what you are saying I don't see a logic behind this. (12 years PHP exp) ;) It converts to boolean `true` but integer `0`. I'm currently considering to throw away all my PHP code and convert to java

Comment: The number 0 is always equal to any string - doesn't make all that much sense, but === should be used most of the time anyway - at which point this issue does not occur

Comment: @SmokeyPHP 0 isn't equal to any string. Try `var_dump('1' == 0);`

Comment: @hek2mgl Well yes, any textual string of course - obviously a number cast as a string will be parsed as it's number and be compared correctly.